# Arch Linux Networkmanager Issues

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, gnome, arch-linux, networkmanager

I been having issues with connecting to an encrypted network. All encrpyted networks that are in range show that they have 0 signal in networmanager, however it can see that they are there. When I run `iwlist wlan0 scan` i get:

```
Cell 03 - Address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
                ESSID:"XXXXXXX"
                Protocol:IEEE802.11bg
                Mode:Master
                Channel:11
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:54 Mb/s
                Extra: Rates (Mb/s): 1 2 5.5 11 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54 
                Quality:100  Signal level:0  Noise level:136
                Extra: Last beacon: 1ms ago
```

I can how ever connect to any un-secured network from my phones AP

I have a fresh install of Arch Linux 2010.05 running a 2.6.38 kernel. The wireless card im using is a Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN with vender issued drivers that I have used in previous installations. My desktop enviromnet is Gnome 3

The odd thing is that I just installed this OS on my old hard drive last week and everything worked. I just upgraded to a SSD to replace my hard drive, and I been having issues with the wireless since I started the install.

I tested using wicd, it works, however it kept giving my dbus issues on startup.

I was wondering if any of you would have ideas, if you need more info please feel free to ask.

Comment: You mention "dbus issues on startup". It might be nice to elaborate on those - `dbus` is a really oft-used component in distros these days.

Comment: The wicd dbus isssues were that i didnt start the wicd deamon in my rc.conf...  wicd kinda works for me, however i often get disconnected.

Comment: Does dmesg say anything?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I hadn't checked the date for the question and it didn't answer the question. But my answer involved doing: `mv /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/` because Arch Linux moved the file location recently. Maybe that will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed all necessary packages to connect to secured wireless-networks? Maybe you  forgot to install something?

Take a look at this how to:

[How to install and configure NetworkManager and network-manager-applet on Arch Linux with GNOME3](https://evilshit.wordpress.com/2012/09/15/how-to-make-networkmanager-and-network-manager-applet-work-on-arch-linux-with-gnome3/)